# Posting to Shopify using PHP

Tags: php, json, shopify

I'm trying to post from a PHP page to Shopify to indicate that an order item has been fulfilled. I must not be doing this correctly because I keep getting a null result. I'm doing this on a test order that was cancelled, but I would expect that I'd at least get some sort of non-null response if that were the problem. Here is my code:

```
$API_KEY = 'my-api-key';
$SECRET = 'my-shared-secret';
$PASS = 'my-shopify-password';
$STORE_URL = 'mydomain.myshopify.com';
$ITEM_ID = 'my-item-id';
$ORDER_ID = 'my-order-number';
$TRACKING_NUMBER = '12345';
$TRACKING_URL = 'http:\/\/test.com\/testurl';

$baseUrl = 'https://'.$API_KEY.':'.$PASS.'@'.$STORE_URL.
           '/admin/orders/'.$ORDER_ID.'/fulfillments.json';

$data = array('fulfillment' =>
                array(
                    'tracking_number' => $TRACKING_NUMBER,
                    'tracking_company' => 'USPS',
                    'tracking_url' => $TRACKING_URL,
                    'line_items' =>
                        array(
                            'id'=>$ITEM_ID,
                            ),
                ),
            );
$session = curl_init( $baseUrl );
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

$json = json_decode( $response, true );

var_dump($json);
```

Comment: What are you using to authenticate?  oauth or legacy?

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 I don't know -- this is the first time I've tried posting anything to Shopify, I've only pulled data from Shopify until now. Maybe that's the problem? I'm also seeing in some documentation that I may need to add write_shipping to my "requested scopes" but I see zero info on where to find requested scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Shopify requires the line items to have an additional array, so instead of this:

```
'line_items' =>
                    array(
                        'id'=>$ITEM_ID,
                        )
```

It should be this:

```
'line_items' =>
                    array(
                       array(
                           'id'=>$ITEM_ID,
                        ) 
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a json in the POST section, are you sure this is what you really want to do? The post data should be more like this, sending `data1=test1&data2=test2`. [source](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post)

```
<?php
$API_KEY = 'my-api-key';
$SECRET = 'my-shared-secret';
$PASS = 'my-shopify-password';
$STORE_URL = 'mydomain.myshopify.com';
$ITEM_ID = 'my-item-id';
$ORDER_ID = 'my-order-number';
$TRACKING_NUMBER = '12345';
$TRACKING_URL = 'http:\/\/test.com\/testurl';

$baseUrl = 'https://'.$API_KEY.':'.$PASS.'@'.$STORE_URL.'/admin/orders/'.$ORDER_ID.'/fulfillments.json';

$fields = array(
        'lname' => urlencode($last_name),
        'fname' => urlencode($first_name),
        'title' => urlencode($title),
        'company' => urlencode($institution),
        'age' => urlencode($age),
        'email' => urlencode($email),
        'phone' => urlencode($phone)
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUrl);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);


var_dump($result);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

If you really wants to send JSON via the POST fields, maybe you are missing the length of your data : [source](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)

```
curl_setopt($, , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);
```

Comment: Yes Shopify uses JSON, unless there's another way of doing it that I'm not aware of. Their documentation isn't the best for a newbie. Since the $data variable is an array, not a string, the string length parameter isn't working as you listed. I'm not sure that's what is causing the problem but I'm open to anything.

Comment: Once json_encoded, you can `strlen($json_string)` !

Comment: Thanks Alexis, that helped me get the length. But unfortunately it didn't change my result :( Still null. If the response is null, does that mean it's not posting correctly?

Comment: If you use this endpoint, do you get a response ??  /admin/orders/#{id}/fulfillments.json @Keri -- It should just be a list of all fullfillments so you don't need to pass it any data other than the ID which I think is arbitrary

Comment: @NotoriousPet0, I tried going directly to that URL to see what it says, since in other cases it has shown me the full response on the screen, and the response it shows is {"errors":"Not Found"}. Not a page not found, this is the response it's giving. I changed the ID to one I know had been fulfilled but it gave the same response. I tried removing the order ID to see if it would list all fulfillments and it gave the same response. Do you know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using complete.json instead ???  I may be misunderstanding but it sounds like your trying to complete a pending fulfillment.

```
/admin/orders/#{id}/fulfillments/#{id}/complete.json
```

https://docs.shopify.com/api/fulfillment#complete

Comment: If I use complete.json it doesn't allow me to enter the tracking number, unless I misunderstood. I'm fulfilling using Stamps.com and want to be able to add the tracking number for the customer's shipment.